# Add user ID to Array to be banned upon return to guild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

As stated in the title I'm wanting to extend the current code I have for a ban function (included below).
If a user has left the guild/server how would I add their userID into an Array? This way I can loop through it every time someone joins the guild and check if they were previously banned: if so, they will be properly banned.

So the process would be:

- `<prefix>ban <userid>`
- If the user is not in the guild then add the ID to an Array and display a ban message
- When a new member joins, check them against the Array and if ID exists then ban them and remove them from Array.

```js
 switch (args[0]) {

    case 'ban':
      if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

      if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Moderator') && !message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Staff')) return message.channel.send('You dont not have the required permissions').then(msg => {
        msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
      })
      var user1 = message.mentions.users.first();

      if (member) {
        // There's a valid user, you can do your stuff as usual
        member.ban().then(() => {
          message.channel.send('User has been banned')
        })
         } else {
        let user = message.mentions.users.first(),
          // The ID will be either picked from the mention (if there's one) or from the argument
          // (I used args, I don't know how your variable's called)
          userID = user ? user.id : args[1]


        if (userID) {
          // Read the existing banned ids. You can choose your own path for the JSON file
          let bannedIDs = require('./bannedIDs.json').ids || []

          // If this is a new ID, add it to the array
          if (!bannedIDs.includes(userID)) bannedIDs.push(userID)

          // Save the file
          fs.writeFileSync('./bannedIDs.json', JSON.stringify({ ids: bannedIDs }))

          // You can then send any message you want
          message.channel.send('User added to the list')
        } else {
          message.channel.send('No ID was entered')
        }
      }
  }

}

);
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  let banned = require('./bannedIDs.json').ids || []
  if (banned.includes(member.id)) {
    // The user should be properly banned
    member.ban({
      reason: 'Previously banned by a moderator.'
    })

    // You can also remove them from the array
    let newFile = {
      ids: banned.filter(id => id != member.id)
    }
    fs.writeFileSync('./bannedIDs.json', JSON.stringify(newFile))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, but you'll need to grab the user ID manually since you can't mention someone that's not in the guild (you technically can, but you would need to grab the ID anyway).

If there's no user mention or if there's one, but the user isn't in the guild, you'll need to grab their ID and push it to an array. You may want to save that array in a JSON file so it's kept between reloads: you can use [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) for that.
Here's an example:

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.first()
if (member) {
  // There's a valid user, you can do your stuff as usual
  member.ban().then(() => {
    message.channel.send('User has been banned')
  })
} else {
  let user = message.mentions.users.first(),
    // The ID will be either picked from the mention (if there's one) or from the argument
    // (I used args, I don't know how your variable's called)
    userID = user ? user.id : args[0]

  if (userID) {
    // Read the existing banned ids. You can choose your own path for the JSON file
    let bannedIDs = require('./bannedIDs.json').ids || [] // WRONG: read the edit below

    // If this is a new ID, add it to the array
    if (!bannedIDs.includes(userID)) bannedIDs.push(userID)

    // Save the file
    fs.writeFileSync('./bannedIDs.json', JSON.stringify({ ids: bannedIDs }))

    // You can then send any message you want
    message.channel.send('User added to the list')
  } else {
    message.channel.send('No ID was entered')
  }
}
```

Remember that you have to import the `fs` module, which is included with Node:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
```

Also, create a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  ids: []
}
```

When a new user joins, you can check their ID:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  let banned = require('./bannedIDs.json').ids || [] // WRONG: read the edit below
  if (banned.includes(member.id)) {
    // The user should be properly banned
    member.ban({
      reason: 'Previously banned by a moderator.'
    })

    // You can also remove them from the array
    let newFile = {
      ids: banned.filter(id => id != member.id)
    }
    fs.writeFileSync('./bannedIDs.json', JSON.stringify(newFile))
  }
})
```

---

**Edit:**

How to solve the problem with the array being cached:

1. You load the array only once, when starting the bot, and store it in a variable. Every time you need to read or write to the array you use that variable, and periodically you update the JSON file.
2. As you mentioned in your comment, you can replace the `require()` with [`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options). You can read the file with this `fs` method, and then you can parse the JSON object with the `JSON.parse()` function.
   Here's how you can do it:

```js
// Wrong way to do it:
let bannedIDs = require('./bannedIDs.json').ids || []

// Better way to do it:
let file = fs.readFileSync('./bannedIDs.json')
let bannedIDs = JSON.parse(file).ids || []
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply, very thorough. That being said im still unable to incorporate your suggested code into my own. No matter how i arrange it , it still comes back with "need to specify valid user"

Comment: I have edited my main post to include the updated code to show what i have done(-wrong)

Comment: From what I can see form your code, you've added everything inside the `if` statement in the first line: that means that if you don't mention a member (which you won't if you use the ID) none of that code is going to run

Comment: Can you re-arrange it in such a way where i can learn from this please? I think i have found my current limitation for understanding and knowledge, either that or i have been trying too long

Comment: When you look at `message.mentions.members.first()` you're getting the mentioned member ('@UserName'), but only if that's a user from the guild. If you used the ID then there will be mentioned user, and so you have to put your code for that in the `else` part. I'm not sure which part is the one you're struggling with, I suggest that you try to re-build this entirely by looking at both my example and your code: this way you'll be forced to understand what you're writing, instead of just copy-pasting ;). If after that you still have some questions feel free to ask

Comment: Iv used message.mentions.members.first() to continue my usual method ban routine and then...else...     so IF valid user mention continue to check privilege  normal ban. ELSE your script

Comment: Is user mentioned > check permissions > member.ban + embed message > else >  user = message.mentions.members.first() (so the user ID manually entered)  > read ID's > add ID if new > save the .JSON > display ban embed (confirmation to user command successful)  > else > no id entered message

Comment: _"else > user = message.mentions.members.first() (so the user ID manually entered) > read ID's >"_ This is wrong: if your entering the user ID you're not getting any mention...

Comment: So if thats the wrong process whats the right process?  If you can write it simplified like I have in the correct order then I will re write my script again. Iv written it out so many times, im getting so frustrated I'm at the point of giving up

Comment: I've updated my example: the code was practically already there, I just added the actual ban and the messages.

Comment: thanks for updating it. This produces ``` (!bannedIDs.includes(userID)) bannedIDs.push(userID)
                                   ^

TypeError: bannedIDs.includes is not a function```

Comment: My bad: when writing the answer I forgot that JSON files can only store objects, so you'll need to save the array as a property. I've update my answer

Comment: I FINALLY HAVE IT SORTED, im sorry it took so long, turns out i wasnt that far off but the function error threw me off. Everything now works as expected, tested. Thanks for your time and effort

Comment: Actually thats not 100 % correct. It adds to array and bans on the user return, but, if someone were to write ".ban someoneRandom" will add "someoneRandom"  to the .json file, is there a way to avoid anything but userIDs being stored?

Comment: You'll need to check if that's a number and if has 18 characters

Comment: Hi, thanks, i have implemented both of these functions now too. When testing iv noticed if i ban user, and revoke through discord, the id is removed from the .json file but i keep the test user keeps getting banned until i stop, and restart my script? Why is this? is this because im testing through visual studio code?

Comment: What do you mean by that? If by that you mean that you're using the debugger from VSCode then I would avoid that, I think it's better if you don't use it for now. Try without it and see if you still have this problem

Comment: Im using the terminal inbuilt to visual studio code to test the functionality. after revoking a banned test user, the test user keeps getting banned (ID has been removed from .json) until i stop the script in terminal and re start it again, and then the test user can join again.

Comment: I think this issue is possibly to do with the require.cache of the .json file? but im unsure

Comment: The .json writes and reads and updates perfect but im guessing the .json file actually keeps getting read from the cache, thus my test user keeps getting banned, until i stop and restart the script, allowing the .json file to read from file again?

Comment: okay so from what i understand from researching online, using ** require('./bannedIDs.json') ** means " Require is synchronous function and is called only once, which means the calls receive a cached result. If the file is updated you can't re-read it using this method " However im unsure how to implement fs.readFileSync

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't consider this issue because I'm not used to deal with files in this way. Anyway, I've added how to do that at the end of my answer, I hope it solves the problem for you.

Comment: That has solved the problem for me with a few small alterations. Now i am splitting my huge index.js into command modules, everything is done except this one. The normal ban method works perfect but the ban ID rejects everything passed through it, says it isnt a valid ID. The mod and staff check throws a error too now at 'find'. Im clearly missing something with the command handler. i appreciate your time

Comment: Feel free to open another question if have any other issue ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084896/discord-js-not-writing-data-to-json-file